# Primary and full procedural files in RPG

Tags: ibm-midrange

What is the difference between primary and full procedural files as defined in RPG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primary file uses the RPG logic cycle for reading through your data.  A full procedural file is one where your logic controls access to your data records.  Full procedural files are by far the most common usage.  In fact, I don't think I've ever written a program that uses the logic cycle since school.  I **rarely** see them in the wild.

The RPG logic cycle works roughly like this:

1. Read a record in the *primary* file.
2. Perform level-break calculation specs
3. Move the data from the file area to
   fields in your RPG program
4. Perform detail level calculation
   specs
5. Go back to the beginning.

After the last record is read, the LR indicator gets set and level break calculations are executed and then the program ends.

Comment: Believe me, they are still there. I've written quite a lot of programs with the Program Cycle myself. Always loved the "Total time" indicator.

Maybe, it's because I worked in a different area (Logistics, ERP), or maybe it is just the age ... ;-)

Comment: "Total time". There's an expression I haven't heard in a long time.

Comment: It turns out that PERL also had (has) a mode with cycle logic which is rather reminiscent of early RPG.  That mode is out of favor in both languages, however, every paradigm has moments when it meets the needs of a particular problem rather well.  Now we have gotten away from it, in part for efficiency, and also for more flexible control.  Even when a task is ideally suited at the moment to the cycle, you often find later on that new features require logic that does not fit well into the cycle. And @robertnl, I think it is the age ;-)

Comment: A third option is now generally recommended above Primary files or Full-Procedural.  Embedded SQL enables you to accomplish more, with less code, and more efficiently.

Comment: Yeah,Embedded SQL. Been there, done that, got the T-shirt. It's great and efficient and modern. And I was never able to convince my coworkers to switch from full procedural to SQL (even the younger ones).

So, image this situation. I was doing old-school stuff (cycle), normal stuff (full procedural), and modern stuff (embedded SQL). I was having fun. And still many coworkers only wanted to do the same stuff as the year before, and the year before that. Strange.

Comment: @WarrenT, I have done quite a bit of Perl programming including the cycle logic. I did read that in the manual. It made sense to me, and I have used it a couple of times.

Never realized that it came natural to me as being a old RPG guy. Only now I understand the fluffy eyes of the other programmers. That's funny!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is **COMPLETELY** different in RPG. Same database table, but 100% different way of program logic.

This choice is the heart and soul of RPG programming. Therefore, start reading the [RPG Programmer's guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/books/sc092507.pdf).

If you are new to iSeries programming (and by your other questions I know you are ;-), then use full procedural files. This is simular to other languages and systems.

Even better, use the latest version of ILE RPG. This support all the concepts that you know from other languages (procedures, functions, local variables and free format). Older versions are also quite good and do what they are made for, but their concepts are a little bit more exotic.

Answer (score 1):

A 'P'rimary file is somewhat similar to a SQL `FROM` table. With SQL, you don't need to state explicitly when to read the next row from a table when you run an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement; you only need to state which rows to process with `WHERE` and possibly what actions to take against columns. You have no direct control over the timing of disk I/O in the underlying logic; RPG (and SQL) takes care of that automatically.

But it is also possible to use SQL's `FETCH` statement to have more direct control over individual row processing. You can think of a RPG 'F'ull-procedural file like a SQL `FETCH`ed table. With 'F'ull-procedural processing, you will need to code operations (verbs) such as `READ` or `WRITE` in order to move from record to record.

In that sense, moving from the older culture of RPG 'P'rimary files to the later RPG 'F'ull-procedural files is like going to a more primitive form of database interaction before something more modern like SQL existed.

Yet, concurrent and later on-going advances in the RPG language simultaneously allowed RPG to evolve to today's fully free-form language that has no necessary visual relationship to its early roots as merely a 'R'eport 'P'rogram 'G'enerator. Today, it's effectively used by many systems programmers on IBM i possibly more often than C. (C still has a couple notable advantages, e.g., it has advanced optimizers that aren't available for other languages, bit-level operations such as shifts, etc.; it depends on what functions are needed whether RPG is appropriate or not. Faster development is certainly possible in RPG.)

To understand the uses of 'P'rimary (and 'S'econdary and related) files, it's necessary to understand how the RPG "Cycle" works. If 'F'ull-procedural files are used, you effectively code your own version of a 'cycle'. What you get in return is a 'cycle' that doesn't limit you in any way; the logic is exactly the way you code it to be.